# Do I have to use AppSync for apollo graphql in lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, apollo-server

I'd like to use apollo graphql in a lambda and I found AppSync is for graphql and API Gateway is for REST. Do I have to use `AppSync` for that? 
I also find out a library `apollo-server-lambda` which can be used with `serverless` but I don't want to use `serverless` because all my infrastructure code is written in Terraform. I don't want to bring another IaC library in my application.
So is there a way to use API Gateway with apollo graphql in lambda? If yes, how should I declare API Gateway route for that?

Comment: AppSync is for creation of GraphQL endpoints on AWS. I understood you want to consume existing GraphQL endpoint from your lambda, is that correct? In that case I believe you just can use a GraphQL client library supported by your lambda runtime language.

Comment: Not exactly. What I am looking for is to use API gateway to integrate with lambda for graphql endpoints. I am familiar with API gateway and have no experience on AppSync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. You can just use the API gateway, Lambda, and Apollo Server. Install the npm library `apollo-server-lambda` and Import the required modules.

The current version of Apollo Server Lambda: `2.17.0`

You can create a GraphQL handler using the function `createHandler` provided by Apollo server Lambda.

I am not sure about how it is done using Terraform but you can just declare a route to your handler function via the API gateway.

Make sure your GET and POST requests route to the same handler.

Refer to this documentation for more details: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/deployment/lambda/

Comment: Unfortunately, the link provided only details the `serverless` route. Unsure if this changed between original answer and now.